# Conditional Branch in Lua isn't working for no clear reason?

Tags: lua, sublimetext3, coronasdk

I joined this community because it seems to be awesome, and I'm a new coder, so I'd like to try and improve well and quickly by following the advice of such a nice community. :)

I have a question regarding coding in lua -- right now, I'm using Corona SDK and Sublime Text 3 to code a mobile splash screen, and a title screen. I start out with titleScreen = false, so that I can run the code for the splash screen that will make it true. However, when I finish running the code for the splash screen and make titleScreen = true, the conditional branch for the titlescreen doesn't work! Please help me :( I've done tons of testing, but can't figure out where my error lies.

Here is my code:

```
titleScreen = false
local logo = display.newImage("logo.png", 155, 275)
logo.alpha = 0

local function makeMenuTrue()
    logo:removeSelf()
    print("menu should be TRUE")
    print("WHY DOESN'T IT WORK")
    titleScreen = true  
end

local function fadeOut()
    transition.to(logo, {time = 2000, alpha = 0, onComplete = makeMenuTrue})
end

transition.to(logo, {time = 2000, alpha = 1, onComplete = fadeOut})

if (titleScreen == true) then
    print("NOW IT'S TRUE")
    local mainTheme = audio.loadSound ("mainTheme.wav")
    audio.play(mainTheme)

    display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
    local background1 = display.newImage("Title.png", 155, 275)

    local flare = display.newImage("flare2.png", 40, 30)
    flare.xScale = .5
    flare.yScale = .5
    local flare2 = display.newImage("flare2.png", 400, 70)
    flare2.xScale = .6
    flare2.yScale = .6
    local flare3 = display.newImage("flare2.png", 400, 70)
    flare2.xScale = .4
    flare2.yScale = .4

    local function moveFlare1() 
        transition.to(flare, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare1})
    end
    local function moveFlare2()
        transition.to(flare2, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare2})
    end 
    local function moveFlare3()
        transition.to(flare3, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare3})
    end 

    transition.to(flare, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare1})
    transition.to(flare2, {time=2500, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare2}) 
    transition.to(flare3, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare3}) 

--[[local textbox = display.newRect(160, 214, 320, 90)
textbox:setFillColor(.1, .1, .1, .6)
]]

    local textbox = display.newImage("MessageBack2.png", 155, 254, 320, 90)
    textbox.yScale = .7
    local textline = display.newImage("flare2.png", 0, 228)
    textline.xScale = 20
    textline.yScale = .3
    local textOption = 1

    local prompt1 = display.newText ("Start Game", 155, 230, "Goudy Old Style", 20)
    local prompt2 = display.newText ("Continue", 155, 255, "Goudy Old Style", 20)
    local prompt3 = display.newText ("Exit Game", 155, 280, "Goudy Old Style", 20)
    prompt1:setFillColor(0,0,0)

    local function textShrink()
        transition.to(textline, {time = 150, yScale = .3})
    end

    local function moveTextBox()
        if (textOption == 1) then
            textOption = 2 
            transition.to(textline, {time = 200, y = 253, onComplete = textShrink})
            prompt2:setFillColor(0,0,0)
            prompt1:setFillColor(1,1,1)
        else 
            if (textOption == 2) then
                textOption = 3
                transition.to(textline, {time = 200, y = 278, onComplete = textShrink})
                prompt3:setFillColor(0,0,0)
                prompt2:setFillColor(1,1,1)
            else 
                if (textOption == 3) then 
                    textOption = 1
                    transition.to(textline, {time = 200, y = 228, onComplete = textShrink})
                    prompt1:setFillColor(0,0,0)
                    prompt3:setFillColor(1,1,1)
                end
            end
        end
    end

    local function expandText()
        if (textOption == 1 ) then
            print("object 1 has been tapped????")
        else 
            if (textOption == 2) then
                print("object 2 has been tapped????")
            else 
                if (textOption == 3) then
                    print("object 3 has been tapped????")
                end
            end
        end
    end

    transition.to(textline, {time = 150, yScale = .5, 0, onComplete = moveTextBox})
    textbox:addEventListener("tap", expandText)
    else 
        print("lmao no it's not true")
    end
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that reacts on `titleScreen` value runs exactly after you set `titleScreen` to false. That `if` statements is not in some separate function, so it's called only when you load and run this script, when `makeMenuTrue()` wasn't called even once.

But when/if you load/run it again, you have `titleScreen = false` unconditionally executed, so you can't have `titleScreen` storing any info that could be updated by previous `makeMenuTrue` call.

Split it. Make that `titleScreen` condition check a separate function that is called without reloading script. Or at least check if `titleScreen` variable already exist before forcing it to `false` on script reloading.

Comment: `transition.to()` is called when the script is run, calling `fadeOut()` on completion, which in turn calls `makeMenuTrue()` on completion.

Comment: `makeMenuTrue` will be called. But `if` statement won't be called until script reloaded, and if it will be reloaded after `fadeout()` call, then `titleScreen` will be erased at the very beginning of the script.

Comment: Whoa, thanks! I did  call "makeMenuTrue" once after a couple transitions, using "onComplete", but I can see why that's true. Can I ask for more specification on the "when/if you load/run it again, you have titleScreen = false unconditionally executed, so you can't have titleScreen storing any info that could be updated by previous makeMenuTrue call" part though? I don't quite understand that -- shouldn't the value that was executed as false be updated that makeMenuTrue call? What prevents that? Sorry if I don't quite get it, sometimes the language of this forum is quite complicated for me :)

Comment: Code that reacts on `titleScreen` runs in same block where you set this variable to `false`. I.e. `if` will be checking value of `titleScreen` either before `fadeOut()` was called, or after `titleScreen` was set to `false` in the first line of script. Either way `if` statement after `transition.to()` will never see `true` in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use function (`showTitleScreen`) instead of variable (`titleScreen`). All your code from `if-else` statement I put in body of function.

```
local logo = display.newImage("logo.png", 155, 275)
logo.alpha = 0

local function makeMenuTrue()
    logo:removeSelf()
    print("menu should be TRUE")
    print("WHY DOESN'T IT WORK")
    showTitleScreen()
end

local function fadeOut()
    transition.to(logo, {time = 2000, alpha = 0, onComplete = makeMenuTrue})
end

transition.to(logo, {time = 2000, alpha = 1, onComplete = fadeOut})

local function showTitleScreen()
    print("NOW IT'S TRUE")
    local mainTheme = audio.loadSound ("mainTheme.wav")
    audio.play(mainTheme)

    display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
    local background1 = display.newImage("Title.png", 155, 275)

    local flare = display.newImage("flare2.png", 40, 30)
    flare.xScale = .5
    flare.yScale = .5
    local flare2 = display.newImage("flare2.png", 400, 70)
    flare2.xScale = .6
    flare2.yScale = .6
    local flare3 = display.newImage("flare2.png", 400, 70)
    flare2.xScale = .4
    flare2.yScale = .4

    local function moveFlare1() 
        transition.to(flare, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare1})
    end
    local function moveFlare2()
        transition.to(flare2, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare2})
    end 
    local function moveFlare3()
        transition.to(flare3, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare3})
    end 

    transition.to(flare, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare1})
    transition.to(flare2, {time=2500, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare2}) 
    transition.to(flare3, {time=2000, x = math.random(-100, 450), y = math.random(-100, 700), onComplete = moveFlare3}) 

--[[local textbox = display.newRect(160, 214, 320, 90)
textbox:setFillColor(.1, .1, .1, .6)
]]

    local textbox = display.newImage("MessageBack2.png", 155, 254, 320, 90)
    textbox.yScale = .7
    local textline = display.newImage("flare2.png", 0, 228)
    textline.xScale = 20
    textline.yScale = .3
    local textOption = 1

    local prompt1 = display.newText ("Start Game", 155, 230, "Goudy Old Style", 20)
    local prompt2 = display.newText ("Continue", 155, 255, "Goudy Old Style", 20)
    local prompt3 = display.newText ("Exit Game", 155, 280, "Goudy Old Style", 20)
    prompt1:setFillColor(0,0,0)

    local function textShrink()
        transition.to(textline, {time = 150, yScale = .3})
    end

    local function moveTextBox()
        if (textOption == 1) then
            textOption = 2 
            transition.to(textline, {time = 200, y = 253, onComplete = textShrink})
            prompt2:setFillColor(0,0,0)
            prompt1:setFillColor(1,1,1)
        else 
            if (textOption == 2) then
                textOption = 3
                transition.to(textline, {time = 200, y = 278, onComplete = textShrink})
                prompt3:setFillColor(0,0,0)
                prompt2:setFillColor(1,1,1)
            else 
                if (textOption == 3) then 
                    textOption = 1
                    transition.to(textline, {time = 200, y = 228, onComplete = textShrink})
                    prompt1:setFillColor(0,0,0)
                    prompt3:setFillColor(1,1,1)
                end
            end
        end
    end

    local function expandText()
        if (textOption == 1 ) then
            print("object 1 has been tapped????")
        else 
            if (textOption == 2) then
                print("object 2 has been tapped????")
            else 
                if (textOption == 3) then
                    print("object 3 has been tapped????")
                end
            end
        end
    end

    transition.to(textline, {time = 150, yScale = .5, 0, onComplete = moveTextBox})
    textbox:addEventListener("tap", expandText)
end
```